# If $f$ is differentiable everywhere, then choose the correct option/options:

Tags: calculus, derivatives

If $f$ is differentiable everywhere, then choose the correct option/options:

($A$) $|f|$ is differentiable everywhere.

($B$) $|f|^2$ is differentiable everywhere.

($C$) $f|f|$ is not differentiable at some point.

($D$) None of these

I see that first option is wrong as $f(x)=x$ is differentiable but $f(x)=|x|$ is not.

Second looks correct as $|f|^2=f^2$ but not so sure about third.

Comment: Just take $f \equiv 1$ as a counterexample for point (C).

Comment: @MichaelCoffey You should turn that into an answer

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

You may prove that if $g$ is differentiable everywhere then $g^2$ too. Now observe that
$$f(x)|f(x)|=\frac12\left[(f(x)+|f(x)|)^2-2(f(x))^2\right]$$